# What is causing these Windows 10 graphics glitches?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card

I have a Dell Precision T3600 (about 12 years old), with an Nvidia Quadro K2000 graphics card, running Windows 10 Pro.

A few days ago I noticed a problem with the graphics: the odd pixel in the wrong colour, short horizontal lines, small squares in random places. I checked the display cable, reinstalled the latest graphics card driver, restored Windows to a week ago -- the problem remains.

My worry is that it's a problem with the graphics card. Some glitches show in this screen shot:

[image]

What is causing them and how do I fix them?

*Update:*

I've noticed that the glitches do not appear in all windows. Web (both Firefox and Edge), file explorer, Wavelab, among others are unaffected. However, they're clearly visible on the Windows Start menu, groove music, the login screen and settings windows -- among others.

Comment: Odd. How old is this PC? Has the machine worked well in the past? Did it experience anything odd physically in the past few days? Like maybe the PC being exposed to extreme heat or cold? This all seems like a GPU issue. Reinstalling video drivers would be a good first step. Past that, it might sadly be a physical issue with the GPU itself.

Comment: "I checked the display cable, reinstalled the latest graphics card driver, restored Windows to a week ago"  <--  Can you try a different display and see if it has the same issue?  If so, it points to a hardware issue with the GPU.

Comment: It can't be a display [or any hardware] issue if you can screenshot it.

Comment: The machine is about 12 years old. It's my main workhorse. I haven't had any graphics issues until this.

Comment: In the screenshot the problem is around the text. Is it always this way? (Note: 12 years is very long for a computer.)

Comment: The squares makes me think it is a copying from memory compositing issue. One of your memory chips or channels may have failed on your graphics card.